# How can I order a table from another table's column then run a query?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a website for our ball team for the fun of it and keeping track of stats using PHP and SQL for the database.  I've learned both by reading the manuals and through forums.  I'm working on building a query that will display the current longest hitting streak.  I stumbled across a page about detecting runs and streaks and am trying to work with that.  I'm really new to all this stuff, so maybe I've structured my tables incorrectly.

Table "games"

```
+--------+------------+------+
| GameID |    Date    | Time |
+--------+------------+------+
|      1 | 2015/08/19 | 6:30 |
|      2 | 2015/08/20 | 6:30 |
|      3 | 2015/08/22 | 6:30 |
|      4 | 2015/08/24 | 8:00 |
|      5 | 2015/08/24 | 6:30 |
|      6 | 2015/07/15 | 8:00 |
+--------+------------+------+
```

Table "player"

```
+--------+----+---+
| GameID | AB | H |
+--------+----+---+
|      1 |  3 | 1 |
|      2 |  4 | 2 |
|      3 |  2 | 0 |
|      4 |  3 | 0 |
|      5 |  2 | 1 |
|      6 |  3 | 0 |
+--------+----+---+
```

Code

```
SELECT games.GameID, GR.H, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM player G 
    WHERE (CASE WHEN G.H > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> (CASE WHEN GR.H > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    AND G.GameID <= GR.GameID) as RunGroup 
FROM player GR
INNER JOIN games
ON GR.gameID = games.GameID
ORDER BY Date ASC, Time ASC
```

Basically in order to correctly get the hit streak right, I need to reorder the GameIDs on the "player" table based on the Date (ASC) and Time (ASC) on the "games" table before executing the RunGroup part of the code.  Obviously by adding the ORDER BY, everything gets sorted only after the RunGroup has finished querying and results in incorrect data.  I've been stuck here for a few days and now need some help.

The Result I currently get is:

```
+--------+---+----------+
| GameID | H | RunGroup |
+--------+---+----------+
|      6 | 0 |        3 |
|      1 | 1 |        0 |
|      2 | 2 |        0 |
|      3 | 0 |        2 |
|      5 | 1 |        2 |
|      4 | 0 |        2 |
+--------+---+----------+
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
+--------+---+----------+
| GameID | H | RunGroup |
+--------+---+----------+
|      6 | 0 |        0 |
|      1 | 1 |        1 |
|      2 | 2 |        1 |
|      3 | 0 |        2 |
|      5 | 1 |        2 |
|      4 | 0 |        3 |
+--------+---+----------+
```

Thanks

Comment: So there's only one player? And note that date and time are normally stored as a single entity.

Comment: There are around 50 different players, each having up to 300 entries

Comment: How do you differentiate players? And I'm assuming AB = 'at bat', and H = 'Hits', so (not that it matters much but) it might be an idea to clarify that

Comment: each player has its own table. (player1, player 2, player3 and so on).  Correct on AB and H.  I was thinking of just getting the query built for one player, then on the PHP side i could run the query for each player table in the database.

Comment: Ah. Now that IS a terrible idea. Fix that, then get back to us!

Comment: Again, new to all this, so just asking me to "fix that" isn't very specific.  I'm open to fixing anything, but maybe a little pointer to get me going would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: One table: `player_id*, game_id*,ab,h (* = component of PRIMARY KEY)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS games;

CREATE TABLE games
(game_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,date_played DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO games VALUES
(1,'2015/08/19 18:30:00'),
(2,'2015/08/20 18:30:00'),
(3,'2015/08/22 18:30:00'),
(4,'2015/08/24 20:00:00'),
(5,'2015/08/24 18:30:00'),
(6,'2015/07/15 20:00:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stats;

CREATE TABLE stats
(player_id INT NOT NULL
,game_id INT NOT NULL
,at_bat INT NOT NULL
,hits INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(player_id,game_id)
);

INSERT INTO stats VALUES
(1,1,3,1),
(1,2,4,2),
(1,3,2,0),
(1,4,3,0),
(1,5,2,1),
(1,6,3,0),
(2,1,2,1),
(2,2,3,2),
(2,3,3,0),
(2,4,3,1),
(2,5,2,1),
(2,6,3,0);

SELECT x.*
     , SUM(y.at_bat) runningAB
     , SUM(y.hits) runningH 
     , SUM(y.hits)/SUM(y.at_bat) BA   
  FROM 
     (
       SELECT s.*, g.date_played FROM stats s JOIN games g ON g.game_id = s.game_id
     ) x
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT s.*, g.date_played FROM stats s JOIN games g ON g.game_id = s.game_id
     ) y
    ON y.player_id = x.player_id 
   AND y.date_played <= x.date_played
 GROUP 
    BY x.player_id
     , x.date_played;

+-----------+---------+--------+------+---------------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| player_id | game_id | at_bat | hits | date_played         | runningAB | runningH | BA     |
+-----------+---------+--------+------+---------------------+-----------+----------+--------+
|         1 |       6 |      3 |    0 | 2015-07-15 20:00:00 |         3 |        0 | 0.0000 |
|         1 |       1 |      3 |    1 | 2015-08-19 18:30:00 |         6 |        1 | 0.1667 |
|         1 |       2 |      4 |    2 | 2015-08-20 18:30:00 |        10 |        3 | 0.3000 |
|         1 |       3 |      2 |    0 | 2015-08-22 18:30:00 |        12 |        3 | 0.2500 |
|         1 |       5 |      2 |    1 | 2015-08-24 18:30:00 |        14 |        4 | 0.2857 |
|         1 |       4 |      3 |    0 | 2015-08-24 20:00:00 |        17 |        4 | 0.2353 |
|         2 |       6 |      3 |    0 | 2015-07-15 20:00:00 |         3 |        0 | 0.0000 |
|         2 |       1 |      2 |    1 | 2015-08-19 18:30:00 |         5 |        1 | 0.2000 |
|         2 |       2 |      3 |    2 | 2015-08-20 18:30:00 |         8 |        3 | 0.3750 |
|         2 |       3 |      3 |    0 | 2015-08-22 18:30:00 |        11 |        3 | 0.2727 |
|         2 |       5 |      2 |    1 | 2015-08-24 18:30:00 |        13 |        4 | 0.3077 |
|         2 |       4 |      3 |    1 | 2015-08-24 20:00:00 |        16 |        5 | 0.3125 |
+-----------+---------+--------+------+---------------------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Ah, ok thanks.  I guess I'll rebuild my database more like this for better efficiency, I can manage that.  Maybe I didn't explain correctly in my question, but I'm not looking for a running total of Hits.  The runningH column should look like this 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3.  I want to treat column H as 0 or 1 (anything greater than 0 equals 1).  Then runningH calculates how many different values in H precede the current one.  For example, for the 5th entry where H=5, runningH would calculate how many entries before that equal 0.  Answer would be 2.  Hopefully I'm making more sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt my database to have only one table to contain the stats from all players. From there i was able to use this query to find my longest current hitting streak for a certain player.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN h > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As H, MIN(date_played) as StartDate, 
MAX(date_played) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as Games
FROM (SELECT date_played, (CASE WHEN h > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as H, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM stats G WHERE ((CASE WHEN G.h > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> (CASE WHEN GR.h > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
AND G.date_played <= GR.date_played AND player_id = 13) as RunGroup 
FROM stats GR
WHERE player_id = 13) A
GROUP BY H, RunGroup
ORDER BY Min(date_played)) A
WHERE H = 1
ORDER BY Games DESC 
LIMIT 1
```